# Calculating $p^n_{11}$ in a Markov Chain with Complex Eigenvalues

Tags: complex-numbers, markov-chains, self-learning

I have recently started learning Markov Chains and feel somewhat out of my depth, as im not a mathematics student. I am trying to calculate $p^n_{11}$ for a 3 state chain with the following transition matrix and eigenvalues:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/3 & 1/6 \\
0 & 1/3 & 2/3 \\
1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

> 1 , $\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}i}{6}$, $\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}i}{6}$

You can represent $p^n_{11}$ as:

> $p^n_{11} = C_1(1)^n + C_2(\frac{1 + \sqrt{5}i}{6})^n + C_3(\frac{1 - \sqrt{5}i}{6})^n$

Also:

> $(\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}i}{6})^n = (\frac{1}{6})^nr^n[\beta cos(n\theta) + \gamma sin(n\theta)]$

Where $r$ is the modulus and $\theta$ is the argument of the complex number.

> $p^n_{11} = \alpha + (\frac{1}{6})^n(\sqrt{6})^n[\beta cos(n*arctan(\sqrt{5})) + \gamma sin(n*arctan(\sqrt{5}))]$

This was tractable and simple to solve when the complex nuumber was something like $\frac{i}{2}$.
With this problem, you get the argument as $arctan(\sqrt{5})$ which makes it difficult to solve the system of equations you get when you input the initial conditions.
The system of equations is:

$\alpha + \beta = 1 $ since $p^0_{11} = 1$

$\alpha + \frac{\beta}{6} + \frac{\gamma \sqrt{5}}{6} = 1/2 $ since $p^1_{11} = 1/2$

For $n=2$, you get $sin(2*arctan(\sqrt{5})) \approx 0.74535...$ which I evaluated using an online calculator. This becomes difficult to solve the equations. I am stuck here. Could you please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: $C_1=\frac25$ from the stable distribution $(\frac25,\frac15,\frac25)$.  The remainder is related to [OEIS A138229](https://oeis.org/A138229)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I managed to figure it out shortly after I posted the question using trignometric identities. I already knew $C_1$ must be 0.4, but did not know how to show the calculation. Im afraid I do not understand what is in the link you shared. What is the remainder related to?

Comment: You will find $p^n_{11}=\frac25 + \frac{a_{n-1}}{10 \times 6^{n-1}}$ where $a_{n-1}$ are the terms in OEIS A138229.  So in this case $\frac25 + \frac{18976}{604661760}$